Can I run a script on multiple Ruby on Rails server instances?
I want to update a class variable @@banners on all of my 10 instances of Ruby on Rails production servers by a single click of button on any one of the server. Is there a way to do this?
I have the script ready as Banner.reload_banners.
Also is there a way that I can get my server's public IP in the Ruby on Rails production server?
When I click on the button, currently it only reload @@banners in only on that IP where that request was transferred to by load balancer.

I would use a value in the DB and update it (works if all instance use the same DB of course). Also knowing about your public IP is a second question, and depends on the context. I have no answer for that, but I strongly suggest you post another question for that.

The whole point of using the class variable was to reduce the DB hits, so setting/unsetting a value in DB doesn't work for me, as it will have to check that value every time it uses that variable to let know when to update it and when to not. So, is there any other way to achieve this?

Rails – as a web application – communicates with the outside via HTTP. You could provide an API endpoint for reloading the banners. Your script would then have to send a HTTP call to each instance.

A simpler approach is to keep an expiry time in each instance along with @@banners, e.g. 5 minutes. Once the expiry time is reached, the instance updates the banners from the database and set a new expiry time. This way, you don't even need an external script.

Storing the value in a database is probably the best option. I guess your application has already a database, updating the value from one instance will update it all on all others too, and the updated value will be persisted – even when you restart or re-deploy application (which would reset @@banners otherwise).

Updating a variable on your server is never a valid end goal as they are not actually persistent in a reliable way.
While Rails will keep some classes in memory between requests in production any restart will reset the value to nil.
Both class and instance variables are just tools to be used for shuffling data between HTTP and a database, memcached or an external API.
There are also the inherent thread safety issues tied to class variables.
In this case you could also potentially use a service based architecture where the banners are provided by a separate app via HTTP.
